# If $PA - PB$ becomes constant $K$ while $A$ and $B$ are two fixed points ,then the locus of the point is ahyperbola. Is this definition complete?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

If $PA  - PB$ becomes constant $2a$ while $A$ and $B$ are two fixed points with the distance between them $2c$ ,then the locus of the point is a hyperbola.

Is this definition complete?

I do not think this definition is complete as  $a \geq c$ does not  give a hyperbola.
I got confused when I see the definition of hyperbola in wikipedia. Please have a look the following definition from wiki.[image]

Now if we suppose the $PA - PB  > $the distance between $A$ and $B$ then also we will have a problem as $c^2 - a^2 <0$ will make $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{(c^2 - a^2)} = 1$ a ellipse's equation and in ellipse we know that $PA + PB =2a$. Please have a look the following part for better understanding.[image]

I am really confused. Can anyone please help me to clear my doubt?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Definition_of_a_hyperbola_as_locus_of_points

Comment: what do you mean? Can you please elaborate? @labbhattacharjee

Comment: *"Now if we suppose the $PA−PB<
\text{the distance between}\;A\;\text{and}\;B$ then also we will have a problem as $c^2−a^2<0$."* ... Since $PA-PB=2a$ and $AB=2c$, the supposition is that $2a<2c$; that is, $(0<)\,a<c$ and thus also $a^2<c^2$, so that $c^2-a^2 > 0$. No problem. (By the way: It should be $|PA-PB|=2a$, or else the locus is just one branch of the hyperbola.)

Comment: sorry sorry it should be greater than ...@blue

Comment: @cmi: Then what's the problem? If $c^2-a^2>0$, then $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{c^2-a^2}=1$ is *not* an ellipse equation.

Comment: If $c^2 - a^2 < 0$ then the equation will become an ellipse..Can you please read the question once again..@Blue

Comment: @cmi: Oh, I thought you were agreeing that "$c^2-a^2$ should be greater than $0$". I see now that you've edited the question to make $a$ greater than (or equal to) $c$. Well, then, yes: there's a problem. If $PA-PB=2a\geq 2c = AB$, then $PA\geq AB+PB$ in $\triangle ABP$. That would violate the [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), so we needn't consider this case. (Actually, equality ($a=c$) is allowed, which corresponds to a degenerate case of the Triangle Inequality; the result is a degenerate hyperbola.)

Comment: That is what I am trying to say. Wikipedia may have given a wrong definition of Hyperbola...@Blue

Comment: @cmi: So, you're just wondering why Wikipedia didn't explicitly state the requirement $a<c$? That's a valid complaint. While there *are* eventually references to eccentricity ($c/a$) being greater than $1$ for a hyperbola, the condition isn't as prominent as it really should be, and I don't see any justification given for it. ... That being so: *Fix it!* :)  Wikipedia is edited by "the people", and you're a people. You could add a note somewhere early on that says simply "By the (strict) Triangle Inequality [w/ a link thereto], we must have $a<c$." (Does the Ellipse entry need a counterpart?)

Comment: Thank You f0or clearing my doubt@Blue